# How to have smart-table parse content as HTML / conditional formatting

Tags: angularjs, smart-table, ngsanitize

I know that I can format a cell to parse content as a link in ng-repeat:

```
<a ng-href="{{::domainname}}/{{::row.sector}}/{{::row.cname}}/ipo-{{::row.tickerbb}}.html">{{::row.cname}}</a>
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksutine/h7yjxpna/).

How do I make it dynamic, so that if row.tickerbb is null - show a different URL?
I tried to do it in the controller, looping through the data:

```
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function () {
    if (data[i].tickerbb != null) {
        data[i].cname = '<a title="' + data[i].cname + '"' + ' ng-href="' + domainname + '/' + data[i].sector + '/' + data[i].shortcname + '/ipo-' + data[i].tickerbb + '.html">' + data[i].cname + '</a>';
    }
    else {
        data[i].cname = '<a title="' + data[i].cname + '" href="Holdings">' + data[i].cname + '</a>';
    }
    i += 1;
})
```

But the results show up as raw html tags:

[image]

How do I do conditional formatting of the smart-table cell? Or is there a way to sanitize cells in smart-tables?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by constructing my link in the controller:

```
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function () {
     data[i].weight = (data[i].weight * 100).toFixed(2) + '%';
     if (data[i].shortcname != null) {
         var cname = data[i].cname;
         var sector = data[i].sector;
         var shortcname = data[i].shortcname;
         var tic = data[i].tickerbb;
         var url = '<a title="' + cname + '" href="' + $scope.domainname + '/' + sector + '/' + shortcname + '/ipo-' + tic + '.html">' + cname + '</a>';
                        data[i].cname = url;
      }
      else 
      {
          data[i].cname = '<a title="' + data[i].cname + '" href="Holdings">' + data[i].cname + '</a>';
      }
      i += 1;
 })
```

And then sanitizing it inside ng-repeat:

```
<td ng-bind-html="row.cname"></td>
```